# How rotate matrix

Tags: tables

How can I rotate my matrix and put a header on each column?, this my code

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tiny
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{matrix}
    \left[\rule{0pt}{20pt}\right.\!\!\!\!\!
    &\begin{bmatrix}
    -1.235 & 2.131 & -1.815 & 0.738 & 0.571 & -0.561 & -0.57 
     0.219 & -0.417 & -0.109 & -0.265 & -0.418 & 0.459 & -0.401 
     -0.28 & 1.07 & 1.858 & 2.025 & -1.154 & 0.009 & 1.724 
     -0.255 & 1.146 & -0.327 & -0.108 & 0.347 & -0.739 \end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
    &\begin{bmatrix}
    -0.903 & 0.539 & -0.836 & 0.728 & -1.328 & -0.443 & -1.009 
     1.156 & -0.05 & -0.449 & 0.385 & -0.48 & 0.904 & -0.395 
     -2.008 & -0.152 & 0.325 & -0.353 & 0.448 & -0.163 & 1.207 
     -0.167 & 0.413 & -0.627 & -0.556 & 0.018 & -0.276 \end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
     \end{matrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I want to rotate my matrix, 
And I want to put a title in each column.

**I want to rotate it so that each vertex enters the leaf without dividing**
[image]

Comment: @marmot 
I want to rotate it so that each vertex enters the leaf without dividing

Comment: @marmot 
or how can I get the matrix with each vertex in a row

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate stuff with `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<stuff>}`, which comes with the `graphicx` package. Whether I would do that in this context is a completely different story.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} \text{title} & \text{title} \\
\rotatebox{90}{$\begin{bmatrix}
-1.235 & 2.131 & -1.815 & 0.738 & 0.571 & -0.561 & -0.57 \\
 0.219 & -0.417 & -0.109 & -0.265 & -0.418 & 0.459 & -0.401\\ 
 -0.28 & 1.07 & 1.858 & 2.025 & -1.154 & 0.009 & 1.724 \\
 -0.255 & 1.146 & -0.327 & -0.108 & 0.347 & -0.739 \end{bmatrix}$}
&\rotatebox{90}{$\begin{bmatrix}
-0.903 & 0.539 & -0.836 & 0.728 & -1.328 & -0.443 & -1.009 \\
 1.156 & -0.05 & -0.449 & 0.385 & -0.48 & 0.904 & -0.395 \\
 -2.008 & -0.152 & 0.325 & -0.353 & 0.448 & -0.163 & 1.207\\ 
 -0.167 & 0.413 & -0.627 & -0.556 & 0.018 & -0.276 \end{bmatrix}$}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some crazy extra:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} \text{title} & \text{title} \\
\rotatebox{-90}{$\begin{bmatrix}
-1.235 & 2.131 & -1.815 & 0.738 & 0.571 & -0.561 & -0.57 \\
 0.219 & -0.417 & -0.109 & -0.265 & -0.418 & 0.459 & -0.401\\ 
 -0.28 & 1.07 & 1.858 & 2.025 & -1.154 & 0.009 & 1.724 \\
 -0.255 & 1.146 & -0.327 & -0.108 & 0.347 & -0.739 \end{bmatrix}$}
&\rotatebox{-90}{$\begin{bmatrix}
\tikzmarknode{n1}{-0.903} & 0.539 & -0.836 & 0.728 & -1.328 & -0.443 &
\tikzmarknode{n7}{-1.009} \\
 1.156 & -0.05 & -0.449 & 0.385 & -0.48 & 0.904 & -0.395 \\
 -2.008 & -0.152 & 0.325 & -0.353 & 0.448 & -0.163 & 1.207\\ 
 -0.167 & 0.413 & -0.627 & -0.556 & 0.018 & -0.276 \end{bmatrix}$}
\end{bmatrix} 
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\coordinate[right=1cm of n1] (x1);
\coordinate[right=1cm of n7] (x7);
\foreach \X in {1,...,7}
{\path let \p1=($(x1)!{(\X-1)/6}!(x7)$) in node at (-5cm+\y1,5cm-\x1) {\X};}
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: or how can I get the matrix with each vertex in a row, rotate is good idea?

Comment: Why do not you respond to my comment?

Comment: @x-rw I was taking a shower, am a free marmot who can choose to sit at the computer or not, and I added  something that resembles your screenshot.

Comment: sorry, but the brackets is rotate

Comment: @x-rw Hey, let's finish this here. My answer will tell others what you do not want. Perhaps some other user will understand what you want. Unfortunately, my [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, so I really have no clue, sorry!